# JMS I18n routes translations are ignored

Tags: symfony, routes, symfony-2.4

I'm trying to use the JMSI18nRoutingBundle to translate my routes. I've installed and configured it like it's shown in the documentation :

composer.json:

```
"jms/i18n-routing-bundle": "1.1.*@dev",
```

AppKernel.php:

```
new JMS\I18nRoutingBundle\JMSI18nRoutingBundle(),
new JMS\TranslationBundle\JMSTranslationBundle(),
```

And config.yml:

```
jms_i18n_routing:
    default_locale: %locale%
    locales: [en, fr]
    catalogue: routes
    strategy: custom
```

Then I'm trying to extract the translations for the routes. The command given in the doc

```
php app/console translation:extract fr --enable-extractor=jms_i18n_routing
```

doesn't work at all, but I found this command on internet that works better:

```
php app/console translation:extract fr --enable-extractor=jms_i18n_routing --bundle="TeduleCoreBundle" --domain="routes"
```

With this, the translations are extracted in a `routes.fr.yml` file in `AcmeCoreBundle/Resources/translations`. The file contains the translations for all the routes in all the locales, instead of only the routes for the `AcmeCoreBundle`  in the `fr` locale like specified in the command, but oh well, it works...

However, when I do a `php app/console router:debug`, none of the routes are translated. Instead, I end up with something like this:

```
en_fr__RG__tedule_app_account_profile        ANY      ANY    ANY /myaccount
en__RG__tedule_app_account_profile           ANY      ANY    ANY /myaccount
fr__RG__tedule_app_account_profile           ANY      ANY    ANY /myaccount
en_fr__RG__tedule_app_account_notifications  ANY      ANY    ANY /myaccount/notifications
en__RG__tedule_app_account_notifications     ANY      ANY    ANY /myaccount/notifications
fr__RG__tedule_app_account_notifications     ANY      ANY    ANY /myaccount/notifications
en_fr__RG__tedule_app_account_password       ANY      ANY    ANY /myaccount/password
en__RG__tedule_app_account_password          ANY      ANY    ANY /myaccount/password
fr__RG__tedule_app_account_password          ANY      ANY    ANY /myaccount/password
```

As you can see, each route appears 3 times (en_fr, en and fr), and the pattern isn't translated according to what I wrote in the `routes.fr.yml` file.

I tried clearing the cache, putting the `routes.fr.yml` file in `app/Resources/translations`, separating the translations between two files `routes.fr.yml` and `routes.en.yml`, nothing works...

Comment: same here, I can't get it to work.

Comment: When I had the problem I switched to another bundle. But after a while I reached a point where it wasn't sufficient for my needs and I really needed the JMS bundle, so I came back to trying making it work. Finally I found a workaround:
I use the command `php app/console translation:extract fr --enable-extractor=jms_i18n_routing --bundle="AppCoreBundle" --domain="routes"` where `AppCoreBundle` can be any bundle since the extractor extracts all the translations of all the bundles. Then I edit the generated file by hand, delete all the en_fr translations and translate the routes myself.

Answer (score 0):

That happens to me too but I solved it by moving the translation files of the routes to the "app/Resources/translations"

This works to me:

```
php app/console translation:extract en_US --bundle=MyBundle --enable-extractor=jms_i18n_routing --output-format=xliff --domain=routes --keep --output-dir=app/Resources/translations
```